# Thunderbolt monitor goes dark

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a 2013 MacBook Pro being used with a Thunderbolt monitor.  It has been working fine.  But just recently, it has begun not mirroring the screen to the monitor when it is closed.  I am running El Capitan, but have been doing so for awhile.  This issue just started yesterday.  When I open up the MacBook, the monitor turns on and displays the mirrored desktop, then goes dark when I shut the MacBook.  Help please.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use this in "closed clamshell mode?"

Comment: Yes. I have been using it that way since I bought them together in 2013 and they have been fine. This is a recent thing of going dark. Since the original post, I noticed that the battery wasn't charging while hooked up to the display cables. So I used the regular charging cable, but still used the display Thunderbolt to the monitor and it is working fine. I guess something happened to the charging part of the display cable that is preventing the MacBook from mirroring when closed. ???

Comment: One of the requirements of using this in "[closed clamshell mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834)" is that your MBP must be connected to AC power.  If when connected to the power adapter on the monitor it fails, but when connected to an external power adapter it works, your problem is with the monitor.  Just to make sure, you're saying it **works** properly when plugged into an **external charger**, correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with that era of MacBookPros. You may be eligible for a the MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program: If you are, they will fix it for free even if you are out of warrantee (I had my mid 2012 repaired under this program.)

Apple has determined that a small percentage of MacBook Pro systems may exhibit distorted video, no video, or unexpected system restarts. These MacBook Pro systems were sold between February 2011 and December 2013.

https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/